# HTML5 Video Duration

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to make something in JavaScript that increases the width of a P tag so that it shows the video duration cleanly, I have tried but all my attempts have failed he's a shorted version of my code.

```
#Video_Progress_Background { position:relative; width:100%; height:5px; background-color: #383838; }
#Video_Progress { height:100%; background-color: #26A310; }

<div id="Video_Progress_Background">
      <p id="Video_Progress"></p>
</div>

var ProgressBar = document.getElementById("Video_Progress");

ProgressBar.style.width = Video.duration;
```

I know this is basic code, I have tried other ways of doing this but all failed this is just what I thought an easier way for you all who want to help to understand my problem. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of a video will be a *Number* of seconds.

The CSS width property takes a *Length*, which must (unless it is `0`) have units.

```
+ "px";
```

Typically, however, you'll want to calculate the progress width using the duration combined with the current time to calculate a percentage.